# Configure Application to run on .NET 2.0 and 4.5

Tags: vb.net, frameworks

I am using Visual Basic Express 2010 and are trying to configure my application to run on a large variety of computers without the need of updating .NET Framework.

My current project has the following settings in app.config:

```
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
```

The target framework is .NET 2.0. One may think that, with these settings, the program should run out of the box on machines with both .NET 2.0 and 4.X

However, when I attempt to run the software on a fresh Windows 8.1 virtual machine, I run into the following error:

[image: Cannot run on Windows 8]

I'd rather not have my users install .NET 3.5 if it's not necessary. Is there a way to get past this?

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: Your evidently using something from that framework (check references), otherwise it shouldn't require the framework.

Comment: Why have the user install it? Just bundle it with the installer and be done with it.